# How to resize a SwiftUI view to fit its content from a UIHostingController

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, google-maps-sdk-ios

How do you have a SwiftUI view fit its content from a `UIHostingController`?

Here's an example. It works if I manually adjust the frame to an arbitrary size, but I can't seem to get it to automatically adjust the frame for it's content like it would in a normal SwiftUI view.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

struct HelloWorld: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: HelloWorld())

        // How do I have this size to the view's bounds instead of manually changing the frame?
        viewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
        self.view.addSubview(viewController.view)
    }

}
```

My use case here is I want to use a SwiftUI view in a Google Maps marker for its `iconView` property.

It seems like the proper way to do this is to add the UIHostingController as a child view controller and set this property for iOS 16.

```
viewController.sizingOptions =  [.intrinsicContentSize]
```

For Google Maps, `GMSMarker` it just accepts a `UIView` for it's `iconView` property.

```
let marker = GMSMarker()
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
marker.title = "Title"
marker.iconView = viewController.view
marker.map = mapView
```

Answer (score 0):

Which view are are you trying to control the sizing from? SwiftUI should size based on size presented from UIKit world or UIKit side should resize to accommodate the swift view size?

Marking the image .resizable() resizes it to fill the frame set on the ViewController.view.frame.

Form more control on swiftUI side if you use a swiftUI view that fills its bounds (ie. takes all the space it was offered by the parent view) like GeometryReader. You can then read the size it was offered in swift and resize the image and text frames / sizes as required in swiftui accordingly.

```
struct HelloWorld: View {
var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geom in
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                //                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .resizable(resizingMode: .stretch)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                    .frame(width: geom.size.width - 50 , height: geom.size.height - 50)
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            .frame(width: geom.size.width  , height: geom.size.width)
            //.padding(8)
            
        }.border(.red)
}
```

}

Comment: I'm having to manually change the size of the view. `viewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)`. I just want it to automatically adjust the frame to fit the content of the SwiftUI view.

Comment: To do that you need the swift view to have accessible size information so the controller view can see it. If you set vars on the swift view that define the size you should be able to access them in UI environment to set the UI frame size. You need to provide the bridge between the two.